# javascript, can't change class on all elements of the same class

Tags: javascript, classname

I need to remove all the classes from an `i` html element. I have a table with many  elements per row. They are:

```
<i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i>
```

I want to change them due a condition, through javascript, like this:

```
<script>
    if(1){//doesn't matter what 'if' is, it's working this part
        document.getElementsByClassName('fa-trash').className = '';
    }
</script>
```

But nothing happends. When I use getElementById it works, but I don't want to use id, because I have many elements. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` method `returns` a `collection` as a NodeList object. The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes.  So you need to update `className` for every item from the query result. For this, you can use `Array.from` method.

> The Array.from() method creates a new Array instance from an
>   array-like or iterable object.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('fa-trash')).forEach(function(item){
    item.className = '';
});
```